# how to run the same task multiple times concurrently on kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

for example, with this code i print with a while true loop the text that is in the inputs, after that is running i want to do it the same but with different text but when i trigger the task it starts printing the new text and the first one no. i tried already with threading and multithreading library but the result is the same

.kv file

```
screen_helper = '''
ScreenManager:
    Loginscreen:


<Loginscreen>:
    name: 'login'
    MDTextField:
        id: emaillogin
        hint_text: "E-mail"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.70}
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 300

    MDTextField:
        id: passwordlogin
        hint_text: "Password"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.60}
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 300

    MDLabel:
        text: "Welcome to Profit Alert"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.7, "center_y": 0.80}
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 500

    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "Sign up"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.45}
        on_press: root.calling()

    MDTextButton:
        text: "Don't have an account?, create a new one"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .25}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'request'

    MDTextButton:
        text: "Forgot password?"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0.35}
        on_press: root.call()
```

.py file

```
class Loginscreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)

    def calling(self, *args):
        executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
        executor.submit(self.func)

    def imprimir(self, *args):
        self.palabra1 = self.ids.emaillogin.text
        self.palabra2 = self.ids.passwordlogin.text

    def func(self, *args):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.imprimir, 0)
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            print(self.palabra1, self.palabra2)

    def call(self, *args):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.imprimir, 1 / 1)

    pass

class work(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Yellow"
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen


work().run()
```

i tried with threading and multiprocessing pool

Answer (score 0):

Let me put it this way a kivy gui it self is a loop u cant put an infinite loop inside the gui cause you will push it to a bug. the only way is use a thread. follow this example and u ll find ur problem.

**Lets say we have a main.py file like this:**

```
import threading
import # what u need 

Builder.load_file('the.kv')

some_cond = False              # Note that this function is gonna be 
string = ''                    #   running on thread and threads can't
some_function():               #    be started twice or stopped 
    global string, some_cond   #     and restarted 
    while True:                # the while True is meant to keep
        if some_cond == True:  #  the thread alive
           print(string)       #      


      
some_thread = threading.Thread(target = some_function)    


class fscreen(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        global string, some_cond        ## dont forget this
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        
        Clock.schedule_interval(update_string, 1) # 1 time per sec
        # this Clock is meant to update the string the outer thread

    def update_string(self, *args):
        global string
        string = self.ids.my_text_input.text   
        #### assuming that some_cond = True the thread is gonna 
        ###    print(string) endlessly  for that u may consider managing 
        ##      some_cond True or False with a Button or something
        #        depends on when and what u want to print

class secscreen(Widget):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        pass
class thscreen(Widget):
    
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        pass        
class theapp(App):
    def build(self):
        
        self.screenm = ScreenManager() #(transition=FadeTransition())

        self.fscreen = fscreen()
        screen = Screen(name = "first screen")
        screen.add_widget(self.fscreen)
        self.screenm.add_widget(screen)

        self.secscreen = secscreen()
        screen  = Screen(name = "secondscreen")
        screen.add_widget(self.secscreen)
        self.screenm.add_widget(screen)

        self.thscreen = thscreen()
        screen  = Screen(name = "thirdscreen")
        screen.add_widget(self.thscreen)
        self.screenm.add_widget(screen)
        return self.screenm

if __name__ == "__main__":
theapp = theapp()            
some_thread.start()                     # this way both the gui and 
threading.Thread(target = theapp.run()) # and the function are threading
```

**Now in ur `the.kv` file i have something like this:**

```
<fscreen>
    
    TextInput:
         id: my_text_input
         size: ## whatever u want
         pos: ## whatever u want
```